# Can a Python class's __str___() return one of two strings?

Tags: python, string, printing

I have a class for which I want to be able to print either a short string representation of an object or a longer string representation. Ideally, `__str__()` would accept a flag that chooses which string to return, and `print()` would accept that flag as well and use the correct version of `__str__()` accordingly, but nothing like that seems to exist.

I know that I can include `print_short()` and `print_long()` methods inside my class to choose the correct string, but this doesn't seem Pythonic, and violates the Python 3 change by which `print()` is a function. This would also bypass the use of `__str__()`, which again, seems unPythonic.

What's the most Pythonic way of handling this? Solutions involving `__repr__()` won't work, since I'm already using `__repr__()` as intended, to unambiguously represent the object itself.

Comment: The most pythonic way I guess, would be to have two methods `short_str` and `long_str`. You can use them as `@property` if you want.

Comment: You could add the flag as an attribute of the object of class, and set it before printing.

Comment: Whatever you do to determine what flag would be passed to `__str__` can be used to choose the appropriate "single-use" function in the first place.

Comment: `__format__` is probably the method you are looking for.

Comment: just use 2 attributes for long and short-form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job of `str` is to provide "the" string representation of an object, whatever representation you decide is most useful.

If you want to control the *formatting* of an object, override `__format__`.

```
class MyClass:

    def __format__(self, spec):
        ...
```

If you have code like

```
s = MyClass()
print("{:r}".format(s))
```

`s.__format__` receives everything after the colon (in this case `r`) as its `spec` parameter; it is then entirely up to the definition of `__format__` how it uses the spec in deciding what string value to return. You could do something like the following

```
class MyClass:
    def __format__(self, spec):
        if spec == 's':
            return self._short_str()
        elif spec == 'l':
            return self._long_str()
        else:
            # This includes both no spec whatsoever, which is
            # conventionally expected to behave like __str__
            # and an unrecognized specification, which is just ignored.
            return str(self)

    def _long_str(self):
        return "three"

    def _short_str(self):
        return "3"

    def __str__(self):
        return "III"

>>> x = MyClass()
>>> str(x)
'III'
>>> "{}".format(x)
'III'
>>> "{:whatever}".format(x)
'III'
>>> "{:s}".format(x)
'3'
>>> "{:l}".format(x)
'three'
```

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you. It does grate on me a bit that, as you said, "The job of str is to provide "the" string representation of an object, whatever representation you decide is most useful.".  I understand why there's one repr, but it seems like there could often be many string representations, all of which would be useful in different contexts. But obviously my gripe about that is with Python, not with your answer. Thank you again.

Comment: `str` being a type, one could argue that `str(x)` never was, nor should have been, the go-to way to produce a string representation of an arbitrary object. Rather, it was convenient that, given an object, `str` should produce *some* useful instance.